# SQL / PHP Insert columns form one table to another

Tags: php, insert

Hi I working on simple newsletter script, I got two groups there with two different tables for each group.

I want to move subscribers from one group to another, I put this query and It works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter_subscribers2 SELECT * FROM newsletter_subscribers WHERE id='".$_GET['nid']."'";
```

However after moving some previous subscribers I got error with duplicated entry key, as I supose query is moved with ID, so I want just move, name, lastname and email.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter_subscribers2 VALUES (firstname, lastname, email) SELECT newsletter_subscribers.firstname, newsletter_subscribers.lastname, newsletter_subscribers.email FROM newsletter_subscribers WHERE id='".$_GET['nid']."'";
```

However this part of code doesnt seemst to work as I got syntax error, can anyone help me with this I will be very happy.

Thanks for reply

Comment: You sure your `id` field is a string ( as you quote it with single quotes ) ?

Comment: _Why_ do you have to different tables – what makes the data you store for each “group” significantly different?

Comment: Agree with @CBroe . If the two groups are semantically of the same nature then they should perhaps be in the same table. If any extra information distinguishes one from the other then that would mean adding an extra table just for those fields. In this case, it sounds like you could have a second table with some ids and names to differentiate the two groups with all records being saved in just one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `values`

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter_subscribers2(firstname, lastname, email) 
   SELECT newsletter_subscribers.firstname, newsletter_subscribers.lastname, 
   newsletter_subscribers.email 
   FROM newsletter_subscribers WHERE id='".$_GET['nid']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the VALUES

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter_subscribers2 (firstname, lastname, email) 
        SELECT newsletter_subscribers.firstname, newsletter_subscribers.lastname, 
               newsletter_subscribers.email 
        FROM newsletter_subscribers WHERE id='".$_GET['nid']."'";
```

Edit: And always use mysql_real_escape_string to prevent SQL-injection:

```
$sql = "... WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nid'])."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into newsletter_subscribers2 (col1, col2, col3, etc) select col1, col2, etc from newsletter_subscribers2  where 1 = 1
```